# PHP cookie not loaded after href?

Tags: php

Basically I have 2 webpages
1 with game where a button takes me to the second

```
<button onclick="window.location.replace('http://karakaip.web.elte.hu/leaderboard.php')" id ="leaderboards">
      Leaderboard
</button>
```

this is to take me to the leaderboard.php

```
<button onclick="window.location.replace('http://karakaip.web.elte.hu')" id ="leaderboards">
      <<
</button>
```

and this to take me back from leaderboard.php to the home page.

The problem is that I use a cookie to store the username of the people. When I open the main page, it gets loaded in, after leaving to leaderboard.php via the button, it's still loaded in, but after using the button to return to the home page, it says that I'm usign 0 cookies, so they are not loaded in, until I restart the page.

Why is this happening and how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie on the path of your project, so the cookie can be accessed on any local of site.

Ex.:

```
setcookie("CookieTeste", $value, time()+3600, "/");
```

Comment: I use a code like this 

`if (!isset($_COOKIE['Name'])) {
        setcookie("Name", $name, time() + (86400 * 5), "/");
        $_SESSION['Name'] = $name;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['Name'] = $_COOKIE['Name'];
        setcookie("Name", $_SESSION['Name'], time() + (86400 * 5), "/");
    }`

To store them. I have this code in a request.php which handles a jQuery $.post request, that gets called whenever the minesweeper game is won.
Sorry for bad formatting I don't think I can use code blocks in mini markdown.

Comment: @pacuhh why are you storing this information in a cookie, _and_ the session? Why do you need both?

Comment: No real reason to be honest, I'm just a bad coder, but it should work regardless of this, I think.

Comment: if you setting SESSION too use  her. Only remember of session_start() on the pages.

Comment: Hey @pacuhh if i help you to resolve you problem give me answer a up vote <3

Comment: Oh sorry, but your answer was not the answer, dumb me used replace, instead of href, and it made all the difference. Thank you tho!